# What circuit depth is enough to compute a log-space complete problem?

Tags: logspace, circuit-depth

To the best of my knowledge it is unknown that  $\mathsf{L}$ is subset of $\mathsf{NC}^1$.

(Here $\mathsf{NC}^1$ is the class of decision problems solvable by a  family of Boolean circuits, with polynomial size, logarithmic depth , and bounded fan-in;

$\mathsf{L}$ is the class of decision problems solvable  by a Turing machine restricted to use an amount of memory logarithmic in the size of the input.)

Let reduce restriction in the definition of $\mathsf{NC}^1$: assume we allow size, say $n^{O(\log \log n)}$ and depth $O(\log n \log \log n)$. Can we solve any problem in $\mathsf{L}$ by such circuits?

Are there any natural conjectures about it?

Comment: $L\subseteq NC^2$ is known and so $n^{O(1)}$ size and depth $O(\log^2n)$ suffices. The OP is asking for tradeoffs between size and depth.

Comment: $NC^2 \subseteq quasiNC^1$ (log-depth, quasi-poly size), and I think this is the best known size upper bound on log-depth circuits to compute $NC^2$ problems. If you ask about size upper bound on log-depth circuits to compute logspace, I don't know if anything better is known (but I kinda doubt it...).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Could you please give a reference about quasi$NC^{1}$? Your definition confuses me:  if depth is $O(\log n)$ and fan-in is bounded then output depends on poly(n) vertices, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexeyMilovanov: Yes, but...vertices of what? There are only n input bits. I'll see if I can dig up a ref about quasiNC^1

Comment: Couldn't easily find a ref, but the idea is: try to turn your NC^2 circuit into a formula (where the underlying DAG of the circuit is a tree), as NC^1 = poly-size formulas. If you do that by duplicating various subcircuits, you increase the size by a factor that is roughly $2^{depth}$. In this case, that's $2^{O(\log^2 n)} = n^{O(\log n)}$.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow This will have depth $O((\log n)^2)$ though, not $O(\log n)$. Indeed, $O(\log n)$ depth bounded fan-in circuits have automatically polynomial size. The correct definition of quasiNC^1 should have depth logarithmic in circuit size rather than in $n$ (so the inclusion of NC^2 in quasiNC^1 is trivial: the $O((\log n)^2)$ depth polynomial-size circuit is a quasiNC^1 circuit as is).

Comment: @Emil: Oh, I guess by "quasiNC^1" I was thinking a formula with bounded fan-in gates, unbounded depth, quasi-poly size. (Since NC^1 = poly-size formulas of unbounded depth.) But, right, that doesn't give you a quasi-poly size log-depth NC circuit, as those don't exist (oops!).

Comment: By the way, in the question, depth $O(\log n\log\log n)$ by itself implies size $n^{O(\log\log n)}$, making the $n^{O(\log n)}$ bound redundant.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that nobody has added to the discussion of this question since February.

I'm quite sure that no better depth upper bound is known for L than $\log^2 n$, in the bounded fan-in circuit model, even with no size restriction.

In the semi-unbounded fan-in circuit model (fan-in 2 AND and unbounded fan-in OR), log-depth is adequate to recognize not only L, but also NL, with polynomial size.  This class, known as $SAC^1$ is equal to the class of problems logspace-reducible to a context-free language, and it has several equivalent characterizations.

The "natural conjecture" would be that $\log^2 n$ is optimal ... but there's not much evidence to support that conjecture.